# SwiftUI: List of subviews with variable height taking extra space

Tags: ios, swift, list, swiftui

I'm dealing with a very strange issue in SwiftUI. Basically, I'm trying to have a list of subviews (`Collapsible()`, in the code below), where each of these views can expand and collapse when tapped. Additionally, these views display one `HStack` for every `item` in the `items` state variable, and there's a button to add one additional item per tap. Each `Collaspible()` looks like this:

[image]

Now, I want to display these Collapsibles in a list. In the code below, I've just added three in a pretty straightforward manner:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Collapsible()
            Collapsible()
            Collapsible()
        }
    }
}
```

That ends up looking like this:

[image]

Here's where the issue comes in. If I expand one of these collapsibles and add some items, this is what happens:

[image]

The list delegates extra room for the `Collapsible()`, even though when it is not expanded, the `maxHeight` is 0. Does anyone know why this is happening and how to avoid it?

Here's the code for the `Collapsible()` struct.

```
struct Collapsible: View {
    @State private var isExpanded: Bool = false
    @State private var items: [String] = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Text("Tap Me")
                Spacer()
                Text("Info")
            }
            .contentShape(Rectangle())
            .onTapGesture {
                isExpanded.toggle()
            }
            
            VStack {
                ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
                    HStack {
                        Text("Item")
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Info")
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical, 5)
                }
                
                Button("Add Item") {
                    items.append("new item")
                }
            }
            .frame(maxHeight: isExpanded ? .none : 0)
            .clipped()
        }
        .background(Color.cyan)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it's the button that occupies the white space you're seeing; when tapping there, it'll continue to call the button's code.

I can't tell you how to solve this with the `.frame()` modifier, but I can offer an alternative: `if`

If you simply use an `if` condition to show/hide the views, it works as you'd expect it to:

```
if isExpanded {
    VStack {
        ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
            HStack {
                Text("Item")
                Spacer()
                Text("Info")
            }
            .padding(.vertical, 5)
        }
            
        Button("Add Item") {
            items.append("new item")
        }
    }
}
```

One additional problem is that adding items with the same value will also have the same identifier, though I assume this is just for the purpose of demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Thanks Michael. The reason that I opted for the .frame() modifier is because eventually, I want to animate the view that appears when you tap to kind of "drop down" from the unexpanded view. Do you know how I could achieve that using the if statement? I've tried it before and the animation always seems very buggy, expanding from the middle outward, rather than from the top down.

Comment: Have you tried it on a real device? On my iPhone it seems to animate the way you want it to.

I haven't dabbled too much with animation, but when I need to I usually come back to this: 
https://developer.apple.com/tutorials/swiftui/animating-views-and-transitions
(or sometimes an article on hackingwithswift.com)

Comment: I have, perhaps I'll make a separate post on that later today and I'll comment the link with the code so you can take a look.

Comment: Here is the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75818815/swiftui-animating-expanding-views-from-the-top-downward